# What is the reason for having '//' in Python?

Tags: python, division

I saw this in someone's code:

```py
y = img_index // num_images
```

where `img_index` is a running index and `num_images` is 3.

When I mess around with `//` in [IPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython), it seems to act just like a division sign (i.e. one forward slash). I was just wondering if there is any reason for having double forward slashes?

Answer (score 639):

In Python 3, they made the `/` operator do a floating-point division, and added the `//` operator to do integer division (i.e., quotient without remainder); whereas in Python 2, the `/` operator was simply integer division, unless one of the operands was already a floating point number.

In Python 2.X:

```
>>> 10/3
3
>>> # To get a floating point number from integer division:
>>> 10.0/3
3.3333333333333335
>>> float(10)/3
3.3333333333333335
```

In Python 3:

```
>>> 10/3
3.3333333333333335
>>> 10//3
3
```

For further reference, see [PEP238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/).

Comment: I actually like this style better... I can remember in atleast one language I've used (VB?) the differentiating factor was `/` vs `\ ` ... but I could never remember which was which!

Comment: The PEP also addresses the fact that backslash is reserved for escape characters or escaping newlines, so that kind of immediately eliminated `\ ` as an operator.

Comment: Thank you, I have been busy with Python 3+ for quite some time, and I never new this, I have always done `int(n/i)`. Great info here!

Comment: Python's 2 approach to "/" is not really bad.  In SQL, we have to deal with it as well.  Its common to see (0.0+variable1)/variable2 or 1.0*variable1/variable2

Comment: This is almost like c++ int purpose when you jsut want to have non float value

Comment: Re *"...the // operator to do integer division"*: [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34217841/integer-division-in-python-3-strange-result-with-negative-number/34217875#34217875) claims *"// is* ***not*** *integer division"*.

Comment: This answer is **wrong.** `//` does not perform integer division. `-5 // 2` results in `-3`, whereas it would be `-2` if it was indeed integer division.

Answer (score 219):

`//` is unconditionally "flooring division", e.g:

```
>>> 4.0//1.5
2.0
```

As you see, even though both operands are `float`s, `//` *still* floors -- so you always know securely what it's going to do.

Single `/` may or may not floor depending on Python release, future imports, and even flags on which Python's run, e.g.:

```
$ python2.6 -Qold -c 'print 2/3'
0
$ python2.6 -Qnew -c 'print 2/3'
0.666666666667
```

As you see, single `/` may floor, **or** it may return a float, based on completely non-local issues, up to and including the value of the `-Q` flag...;-).

So, if and when you **know** you want flooring, *always* use `//`, which guarantees it. If and when you know you **don't** want flooring, slap a `float()` around other operand and use `/`. Any other combination, and you're at the mercy of version, imports, and flags!-)

Comment: Interestingly, the truncating // still returns a float

Comment: The // operator does floored division, not truncating/truncated division.

Comment: This is the more direct answer based on the nature of this question, imho. The higher voted answer is useful but this one makes it crystal clear why you would choose one over the other in Python2.

Comment: @PeterJohnAcklam that's true, but it's strange that // would return a float when, to many people, "floored division" and "integer division" are highly related. What's the most Pythonic way to get an integer from a floor division? int(a//b)?

Comment: @Lucretiel maybe that has changed in later versions of Python?  `type(2//3)` in Python 3.8.6 returns `<class 'int'>` for me.

Answer (score 27):

To complement these other answers, the `//` operator also offers significant (3x) performance benefits over `/`, presuming you want integer division.

```
$ python -m timeit '20.5 // 2'
100,000,000 loops, best of 3: 14.9 nsec per loop

$ python -m timeit '20.5 / 2'
 10,000,000 loops, best of 3: 48.4 nsec per loop

$ python -m timeit '20 / 2'
 10,000,000 loops, best of 3: 43.0 nsec per loop

$ python -m timeit '20 // 2'
100,000,000 loops, best of 3: 14.4 nsec per loop
```

Comment: I tried this with [Python 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Version_3) (Python 3.8.5) and all four ran at ***the same speed***. Sample run: *9.24* nsec, *9.40*, *9.22*, and *9.34* nsec per loop. (CPU: AMD [FX-4300](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_FX_microprocessors#Piledriver_Core_(Vishera,_32_nm)) 3.8 GHz (four cores). Motherboard: Gigabyte Technology GA-970A-DS3P. Operating system: Linux ([Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa) with [Cinnamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(desktop_environment))).)

Comment: Thus, the 3x performance benefits for the `//` operator is disputed.

Comment: Still holds true for Python 2 which is still broadly used to this day

Comment: @MacK: [Turbo C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B) is also broadly used to this day in some places. Famously, some university interns in India are [forced to use Turbo C++ from the 1990s](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-bitter-truths-about-engineering-in-India/answer/Adhokshaj-Mishra) (otherwise they can't complete their degrees). This has also been documented by Joshua Fluke - I don't have the exact reference, but it may be close to [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTxcFhczzSo).

Answer (score 23):

To complement [Alex's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535596/what-is-the-reason-for-having-in-python/1535624#1535624), I would add that starting from Python 2.2.0a2, `from __future__ import division` is a convenient alternative to using lots of `float(…)/…`.  *All* divisions  perform *float* divisions, except those with `//`.  This works with all versions from 2.2.0a2 on.

Answer (score 11):

`//` can be considered an alias to math.floor() for divisions with return value of type `float`. It operates as `no-op` for divisions with return value of type `int`.

```
import math
# let's examine `float` returns
# -------------------------------------
# divide
>>> 1.0 / 2
0.5
# divide and round down
>>> math.floor(1.0/2)
0.0
# divide and round down
>>> 1.0 // 2
0.0

# now let's examine `integer` returns
# -------------------------------------
>>> 1/2
0
>>> 1//2
0
```