# What is the purpose of the `//` operator in python?

Tags: python, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the reason for having '//' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535596/what-is-the-reason-for-having-in-python)

What is the purpose of the `//` operator?

```
x=10
y=2
print x/y
print x//y
```

Both output `5` as the value.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Integer division vs. float division:

```
>>> 5.0/3
3: 1.6666666666666667
>>> 5.0//3
4: 1.0
```

Or as they put it in the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#index-626), `//` is "(floored) quotient of x and y".  The above example was run in Python 2.7.2, which only behaves that way for floating point numbers.  If you were to use integers in 2.7.2 you'd get:

```
>>> 5/3
9: 1
>>> 5//3
10: 1
```

In Python 3.x you get different results, so if you really want the floored version, get into the habit of using `//` as some day it'll matter:

```
Python 3.2.2 (default, Sep  4 2011, 09:51:08) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 5/3
1.6666666666666667
>>> 5//3
1
>>> 5.0/3
1.6666666666666667
>>> 5.0//3
1.0
```

Comment: Just to note: Under Python 2.2 and up, you can do `from __future__ import division` at the top of the file, and `a/b` will behave like Python 3. This is why `a//b`` is present even under 2.x, so as to allow this future behavior which only became the default as of 3.0

Comment: Special +1 for  get into the habit of using // as some day it'll matter: