# Exercise on Summing Digits | What's with n // = 10

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the reason for having ‘//’ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535596/what-is-the-reason-for-having-in-python)

While trying to do an exercise on summing digits, I stumbled on this solution:

```py
def sum_digits(n):
   import math
   total = 0
   for i in range(int(math.log10(n)) + 1):
      total += n % 10
      n //= 10
   return total
```

My question is, what does the second to last line do? How is that proper syntax?

Comment: Disagree on that, I could see the `=` adding additional lack of clarity into the `//=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That implements what is called `floor division`. Floor division (indicated by `//` here) truncates the decimal and returns the integer result, while 'normal' division returns the answer you may 'expect' (with decimals). In Python 3.x, a greater distinction was made between the two, meaning that the two operators return different results. Here is an example using Python 3:

```
>>> 10 / 3
3.3333333333333335
>>> 10 // 3
3
```

Prior to Python 3.x, there is no difference between the two, unless you use the special built-in `from __future__ import division`, which then makes the division operators perform as they would in Python 3.x (this is using Python 2.6.5):

```
In [1]: 10 / 3
Out[1]: 3

In [2]: 10 // 3
Out[2]: 3

In [3]: from __future__ import division

In [4]: 10 / 3
Out[4]: 3.3333333333333335

In [5]: 10 // 3
Out[5]: 3
```

Therefore when you see something like `n //= 10`, it is using the same `+=`/`-=`/`*=`/etc syntax that you may have seen, where it takes the current value of `n` and performs the operation before the equal sign with the following variable as the second argument, returning the result into `n`. For example:

```
In [6]: n = 50

In [7]: n += 10

In [8]: n
Out[8]: 60

In [9]: n -= 20

In [10]: n
Out[10]: 40

In [11]: n //= 10

In [12]: n
Out[12]: 4
```

Comment: I'm not a python guy, but it seems weird to me it's a floor division and not a truncation division.  If you want to simulate integer division, it seems like it would be difficult.

Comment: @xaxxon I may be misinterpreting, but I believe what you're saying is actually the same thing (floor division == truncation division) - the decimal part gets omitted (or more accurately, the `floor` function is run on it, returning the largest integer not greater than `x`. Does that answer the question?

Comment: What is the integer division result of -4 / 3?  It would be -1, right?  But the floor would be -2?

Comment: oh, jesus; ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > -4 / 3
 => -2

Comment: @xaxxon Haha. Yeah, with negatives it is essentially the same thing - largest integer value that is not greater than `x`. So `-4 / 3 = -1.33` would round to 2 (since -1 is greater than -1.33). Here is an article from Guido himself that goes into better detail: http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html

Answer (score 1):

`//` is the floor division operator. It always truncates the return value to the largest integer smaller than or equal to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The second to last line is a combination of operators, in a way, including an uncommon one, which is why it's a little confusing.

Let's piece it apart.

First, `//` in Python is [floor division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/in-python-what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division), which basically is division rounded down to the nearest whole number.   Thus,

```py
>>> 16//5
3
>>> 2//1
2
>>> 4//3
1
>>> 2//5
0
```

Finally, the `=` is there because of a Python syntax that allows one to perform an operation on a variable, and then immediately reassign the result to the variable.  You've probably seen it most commonly in `+=`, as:

```py
>>> a = 5
>>> a += 7
>>> a
12
```

In this case, `//=` means "perform floor division, floor dividing the variable by the second argument, then assign the result to the original input variable."  Thus:

```py
>>> a = 10
>>> a //= 6
>>> a
1
```

Comment: +1 man - sorry, missed you explaining the `+=`/`//=` syntax as I was typing - looks like we're on the same wavelength :)

Comment: Amazing how big a difference the 30 seconds earlier you posted your answer made

Comment: Ha, yeah, it is interesting to watch. I've been on the 30-seconds after side many times - I think it all evens out in the long run :)

Answer (score 0):

for the assignment in Python A += B equals to A = A + B   ,A *= B equals to A = A * B
same thing applies to "Floor Divide" as well , A //= B  equals to A = A // B

Floor Division means return the truncated integer number

```
>>> 5 // 3   # 1.6
   1    # 0.6 will be throw off
```