# Integer division in Python 3 - strange result with negative number

Tags: python, python-3.4, integer-division

I am new to Python, and I am learning operators right now.
I understood that:

- The `/` operator is used for `floating point division` and
- `//` for `integer division`.

**Example:**

```
7//3 = 2
```

And `7//-3=-3`. Why is the answer `-3`?

I am stuck here.

Comment: See also [Why Python's Integer Division Floors](http://python-history.blogspot.com.by/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`//` is not *integer* division, but **floor** division:

```
7/-3  -> -2.33333...
7//-3 -> floor(7/-3) -> floor(-2.33333...) -> -3
```

[`PEP 238`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) on *Changing the Division Operator*:

> The `//` operator will be available to request **floor** division    unambiguously.

See also [Why Python's Integer Division Floors](http://python-history.blogspot.com.by/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html) (thanks to [@eugene y](https://stackoverflow.com/users/244297/eugene-y)) - Basically `7//-3` is `-7//3`, so you want to be able to write:

```
-7 = 3 * q + r
```

With `q` an integer (negative, positive or nul) and `r` an integer such that `0 <= r < 3`. This only works if `q = -3`:

```
-7 = 3 * (-3) + 2
```

Comment: But what about `5//-3`?

Comment: @Kaushik `5 \\ -3` does not exist in python. If you meant `5 // -3`, it's the same explanation as `7 // - 3`, because `-5 = 3 * (-2) + 1`.

Answer (score 8):

`//`  is the operator for *floor division*.

This means that after the division is completed the "floor" function is applied (the value retrieved from the division is rounded down to the nearest integer **regardless** of whether the decimal part is greater or less than .5)

As for your example, be careful to note that for negative answers the floor division operator will still be rounding down (e.g. -5/2 --> -2.5 --> -3).