# Division(//) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't understand the output of this code.

```py
print(1//.2)
print(10//2)
```

The output of 1st is 4.0
and output of 2nd is 5

Comment: What isn't clear?

Comment: Floating point values are approximations.

Comment: Since the question was prematurely closed, the answer is that the real number 0.2 has no exact representation as a floating-point value; the value you get is slightly larger than 0.2. As a result, `1 // 0.2` is slightly less than 5, and the `//` operator floors that to 4.0.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535596/what-is-the-reason-for-having-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify this, the // operator will give you the integer part of the result. So:

```
10 // 2 = 5
11 // 2 = 5
12 // 2 = 6
```

To get the rest you can use the modulo operator %:

```
10 % 2 = 0 
11 % 2 = 1
12 % 2 = 0
```

Now, when you specify 0.2, this is taken as a floating point value. These are not 100% accurate in the way the system stores them, meaning the exact value of this is likely something like 0.2000000000000000001.

This means that when you do:

```
1 // 0.2
```

What you are really doing is:

```
1 // 0.2000000000000001
```

Which if course evaluates to 4. If you then try the modulo operator, you will see you get a value less than 0.2. When I ran this I saw:

```
>>> 1 // 0.2
4.0
>>> 1 % 0.2
0.19999999999999996
```

Comment: More specifically `//` is known as a floor division.