# Why does this n choose r python code not work?

Tags: python-3.x

These 2 variations of n choose r code got different answer although followed the correct definition

I saw that this code works,

```py
import math
def nCr(n,r):
    f = math.factorial
    return f(n) // f(r) // f(n-r)
```

But mine did not:

```py
import math
def nCr(n,r):
    f = math.factorial
    return int(f(n) / (f(r) * f(n-r)))
```

Use test case `nCr(80,20)` will show the difference in result. Please advise why are they different in Python 3, thank you!

No error message. The right answer should be `3535316142212174320`, but mine got `3535316142212174336`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the reason for having '//' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535596/what-is-the-reason-for-having-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

That's because `int(a / b)` isn't the same as `a // b`.

`int(a / b)` evaluates `a / b` first, which is *floating-point division*. And floating-point numbers are prone to inaccuracies, roundoff errors and the like, as `.1 + .2 == 0.30000000000000004`. So, at some point, your code attempts to divide really big numbers, which causes roundoff errors since floating-point numbers are of *fixed size*, and thus cannot be infinitely precise.

`a // b` is *integer division*, which is a different thing. Python's integers *can* be arbitrarily huge, and their division doesn't cause roundoff errors, so you get the correct result.

Speaking about floating-point numbers being of *fixed size*. Take a look at this:

```
>>> import math
>>> f = math.factorial
>>> f(20) * f(80-20)
20244146256600469630315959326642192021057078172611285900283370710785170642770591744000000000000000000
>>> f(80) / _
3.5353161422121743e+18
```

The number `3.5353161422121743e+18` is represented exactly as shown here: there is *no information* about the digits after the last `3` in `53...43` because there's nowhere to store it. But `int(3.5353161422121743e+18)` must put something there! Yet it doesn't have enough information. So it puts whatever it wants to so that `float(int(3.5353161422121743e+18)) == 3.5353161422121743e+18`.