# Understanding repetition count in a Python String

Tags: python, string

I have this challenge: [Repeated String](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/repeated-string/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=warmup&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen) to solve. I have been trying to solve the challenge but getting failure cos of **Memory Failure**. I cannot help this situation cos the HackerRank platform is not supporting my solution. Might be 32-bit platform.

I have this solution for this, which is quite working for **problem having smaller length**, but I have worked on this thing to learn according to less memory usage.

**My Code:**

```
def repeatedString(s, n):
   if(s != 'a'):
     return len([x for x in (s*n)[:n] if x == 'a'])

   return n
```

Now this throws `Memory Error` error for input having very large length, and string.

I have researched on it, and saw some submissions, and found this out.

**Correct Solution from Leaderboard:**

```
def repeatedString(s, n):
 L = len(s)
 return (s.count('a') * (n//L) + s[:n % L].count('a'))
```

That's it! I got so confused by this solution that I could figure what is actually happening and how. Could anybody please let me know how the above correct solution works? I am new to python and trying my best to get my hands dirty on competitive coding. Thank You!

Comment: what are the parameters passed to the function? I guess first one is string and other is?

Comment: **length**. For more understanding of the question, you can refer to the question link on hackerrank @AkshayNevrekar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is throwing a Memory error because you are constructing a string with the length of the input paramater n.

n can be 10^12, which results in a string with a maximum length 1000 billion letters, which would mean the string you are creating has a possible memory size of **1 terabyte** (Possibly more depending on the encoding of your string).

**So there has to be another way to count the number of a's in a string of that size right?**

Yes (That's why the correct answer is different from your solution).

---

**1. First we get the length of the input string.**

```
L = len(s)
```

For example 'abcde' has a length of 5.

---

**2. Then, we count the number of 'a's in s.**

```
s.count('a')
```

---

**3. Next, we want to know how many times s is repeated as a whole before we reach a string with a length of n.**

```
(n//L)
```

The `//` operator is called [integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535596/what-is-the-reason-for-having-in-python), which results in a whole number. For instance with s='abcde' and n=14, `n//L` equals 2.

---

**4. Multiple the number of 'a's in s by the number of times s can fit into a string of length n.**

```
s.count('a') * (n//L)
```

---

**5. We are almost done, but for our example, something is still missing. 'abcde' can be repeated twice inside a string of length n, but there are still 4 characters left, in our example 'abcd'.**

Here, we construct the remaining string from s with `s[:n % L]`, or in our example `s[:14 % 5]` or `s[:4]`, which results in `'abcd'`.

Then we count the number of 'a's in this string with `s[:n % L].count('a')`

---

**6. Add it all together and we get the function in your answer:**

```
def repeatedString(s, n):
    L = len(s)
    return (s.count('a') * (n//L) + s[:n % L].count('a'))
```

Comment: Thanks Nico, you have a very good briefing skills. Thanks again :)

Comment: No worries! Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

So, the key difference between the two algorithms is that in your original, you do `s*n`, which will actually try to build the *massive* string in-memory. This is why you get the memory error.

The second algorithm essentially says "For a string `s` of length `X` that's repeated out to length `N`, `s` will fit into `M` `N//X` times, possibly with a chunk of `s` left over (the division remainder).

E.g. if your string is `aab` (X=3) and N is 10, you know the string will fit 3 times, with 1 character left over.

So, given there are 2 letter `a` in s, you know that there will be `2*3` a in the first 9 chars. Now you need to deal with the remainder. The final character (the remainder) will be the first character of `s`.

In the second solution, `s.count('a') * (n//L) + s[:n % L].count('a')` is these two parts;

`s.count('a') * (n//L)` - This gives you the `2 * 3` in my example.

`s[:n % L].count('a')` - this gives you the 'remainder' part.