# This code is used to extract each digit from an integer in the reverse order in Python

Tags: python

```
number = 7536

print("Given number", number)

while number > 0:

    digit = number % 10        
    number = number // 10 #(what does "//" do )
    print(digit, end=" ") #(why end=" " )
```

Can you please explain what do last two lines do in this code exactly?

Comment: Please, provide a tittle describing your question, not the context of it

Comment: I recommend to get familiar with the standard Python documentation, and research trivial questions yourself first.

Answer (score 1):

[The `//` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535596/what-is-the-reason-for-having-in-python) performs a floor division (also called integer division). The division is performed and then rounded to the next smallest whole number

The [end parameter](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gfact-50-python-end-parameter-in-print/) on the print function adds a whitespace at the end of the printed value

Answer (score 1):

In `number = number // 10` ,The number will be divided by 10 but the digits after the decimal point are removed(7536 / 10=753.6  but  7536 // 10=753).

The end parameter in the print function is used to add any string at the end of the output of the print statement in python.
By default, the print function ends with a newline. So in `print(digit, end=" ")` after every digit, it would print a space instead of the new line.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.

```
num = 1234
while num > 0: #When num hits 0 stop the loop
    digit = num % 10 #digit=4 - last digit of 1234 = 4
    num = num // 10 #num=123 - 1234/10 = 123.4, drop 0.4 = 123
    print(digit, num)

output:
4, 123
3, 12
2, 1
1, 0
```

In the first run through the loop we make digit equal to the last digit with operation (digit = num % 10),
then we remove the last digit with operation (num = num // 10)

when we start the loop in the 2nd integration, the num is now 123.

[Watch Video](https://youtu.be/BeS_4efa7-U?si=9-VGwLiADqMBFeXk)