# how do i replace a string in a list

Tags: python, string, replace

Im trying to change a string in a list called `lista` composed by n times `|_|`, in a function I'm trying to change one specific place of the list with "X" but nothing is working

```
lista=["|_|","|_|","|_|","|_|","|_|","|_|","|_|","|_|","|_|","|_|"]
```

i want to change only the middle one to `|X|`

I already tried different methods like, the command replace or pop and then insert a new value but nothing as changed and always gives me an error

Comment: Please show the code you've tried

Comment: middle one => there are _ten_ list elements.  There is no middle.

Comment: `lista[len(lista)//2] = "|X|"`? (middle is not well defined for an even number of elements...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code places `"|X|"` in the middle of the list:

```
if len(lista)%2==0:
    lista[int(len(lista)/2)-1]='|X|'
    lista[int(len(lista)/2)]='|X|'
else:
    lista[int(np.floor(len(lista)/2))]='|X|'
```

**Output** When `len(lista)==10`

```
['|_|', '|_|', '|_|', '|_|', '|X|', '|X|', '|_|', '|_|', '|_|', '|_|']
```

**Output** When `len(lista)==11`

```
['|_|', '|_|', '|_|', '|_|', '|_|', '|X|', '|_|', '|_|', '|_|', '|_|', '|_|']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `len(lista) // 2` to get the middle index.

Should there be an un-even number, `// 2` [will 'round' it to the previous integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535596/what-is-the-reason-for-having-in-python), so `9 --> 4`

```py
lista = [ "|_|","|_|","|_|","|_|","|_|","|_|","|_|","|_|","|_|","|_|" ]
middle = len(lista) // 2

lista[middle] = '|X|'

print(lista)
```

```
['|_|', '|_|', '|_|', '|_|', '|_|', '|X|', '|_|', '|_|', '|_|', '|_|']
```

##### [Try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyezuCRRwVYhWkGpJr5GSYcsUiGWKzczJSUnFWhQTmqeBthQTQV9fQUjLi4wJxoiHwtUoF4TUaPOxVVQlJlXAlX5/z8A)

Comment: Didn't OP want a solution in Python? This is in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks @AdamJaamour, did not see that.

Answer (score 1):

```
lista=["|_|","|_|","|_|","|_|","|_|","|_|","|_|","|_|","|_|","|_|"]
lista[ round(len(lista)/2)-1 ] = '|X|'
```

Output:

```
['|_|', '|_|', '|_|', '|_|', '|X|', '|_|', '|_|', '|_|', '|_|', '|_|']
```

Use `-1` because indexes starts from 0